# eosiocpp tool generates different types

Tags: smart-contract, abi

If you look into every ABI file in the contract folder you will find:

```
{
  "version": "eosio::abi/1.0",
  "types": [{
    "new_type_name": "account_name",
    "type": "name"
  }],
  ...
}
```

when I am try to generate an ABI file using `eosiocpp -g ...` I receive:

```
{
  "____comment": "This file was generated by eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT - 2018-05-21T07:24:55",
  "version": "",
  "types": [{
     "new_type_name": "account_name",
     "type": "uint64"
  }],
```

It's very strange that `account_name` is treated as `uint64` not `name`.
Due to this problem, `abi_serializer` tries to parse the string to uint64 and throws an exception.

Did somebody notice it? I am running dawn-v4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which version of EOSIO you are using. If you are using v1.3 or higher, then you should change compilers to use [eosio.cdt](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt), not eosiocpp.

[There are many differences between the two](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt#differences-between-version-12x-and-version-13x), including that an account name now has a dedicated class called `name`, whereas earlier versions just used a `uint64_t`. Other changes include removing the concept of a default asset type, which might also be confusing at first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version problem.

Some types have changed.

See  [Differences between Version 1.2.x and Version 1.3.x](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt#differences-between-version-12x-and-version-13x)